# При выделении конкретного документа справа отобразить содержимое его табличной части с помощью динамического списка

Tags: 1с

Разработать обработку, на форму которой вывести список документов «РасходнаяНакладная». При выделении конкретного документа справа отобразить содержимое его табличной части с помощью динамического списка.

Comment: Покажите код который не работает; Либо детальнее опишите сложности которые испытываете при решении !

Comment: Кода нет, я бы хотел как раз таки посмотреть пример данного задания и разобраться в нем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй сделать сам. Разбей задание на куски:

- создать форму с 2мя таблицами
- вывести список документов
- поставить обработчик "выделение элемента" на первую таблицу
- вывести табличную часть

Как забрать список документов можно посмотреть в форме журнала этих документов, а табличную часть в форме этого документа